# Unable to execute command in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, command-line, permissions

I have been assigned a Ubuntu 12.04 system.I have administrator privilages but when i try to execute command such as ifconfig,sudo etc the command does not executes.I have executed ifconfig command and i have got the following results

> Command 'ifconfig' is available in '/sbin/ifconfig'
>   The command could not be located because '/sbin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
>   This is most likely caused by the lack of administrative privileges associated with your user account.
>   ifconfig: command not found
>   but when i run the command as `/sbin/ifconfig` it executes but the problem is i have to use the entire path rather than just simply typing ifconfig.

Please suggest me what is the problem.And is there any solution for the above problem.
Do help I am new to Ubuntu and i want to work with it any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: it is not only apllicable for ifconfig but also for sudo,gedit,vim etc

Comment: @muru please do not consider as a duplicate question

Comment: Please add the output of `echo $PATH` to your question.

Comment: @heemayl /usr/share/ant//bin:/usr/local/bin

Comment: @blank_007: From command line first run `export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"` and then try `ifconfig` or any other command.

Comment: @blank_007: Its temporary, don't forget what Oli has mentioned in the answer, you need to put that line in the `/etc/environment` file to make it permanent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your PATH variable is knackered. `/etc/environment` should read something like this (this is taken off a 12.04 server):

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

Fix this and you'll fix your problem.

Comment: I tried to fix it in the Path variable but i was unable to set the path variable.

Comment: My /etc/environment contains the Path that u have specified but when it is temporary is there a permanent solution for that

Comment: What do you mean? Setting the PATH in /etc/environment should be permanent. If it isn't taking, something else is changing your PATH variable.

Comment: Every time I open /etc/environment path is set to the above given values but each time I close the terminal and open a new one it again shows me command not found

Comment: That suggests something is breaking PATH elsewhere. Check your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: thanks bro I changed the .bashrc Path variable to the above given path.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your `.bashrc` file on home directory and add the line

`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"`

as above.

Comment: Ya I was trying to makes changes to the .bashrc file but wasn't able to do so.but the export command worked.Anyways thanks for replying